# Android: Touch event for select item on a canvas

Tags: android, touch-event

I have many circles drawn on the Canvas and want to know which of them is touched.
One solution is to create a bitmap as the size of the screen and draw a copy of the circles that are on the screen only with a different color so that when the call getPixel () the bitmap poosso recognize which circle is clicked. My problem is that I do not know how to draw a circle on a bitmap ... that is, how to draw the bitmap as a drawing normally on Canvas.

```
Paint paint;
Bitmap screen;

int w,h;
int px=-1,py=-1; //coordinate 

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    //registriamo le dimensioni della view
    w=MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    h=MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(w,h);
}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;  //Each pixel is stored on 4 bytes
    screen=Bitmap.createBitmap(w,h, conf);

    paint=new Paint(); // pennello
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);   
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);   
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if(px==-1&&py==-1){ // se non abbiamo ancora settato le coordinate, posizioniamo la bmp al centro
        px=w/2-bw/2; //metà della larghezza view, meno metà della figura
        py=h/2-bh/2; //metà dell'altezza view, meno metà della figura
    }

    canvas.drawCircle(px, py, 70, paint);       
}

public void updatePosition(int x, int y) {      

    invalidate();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to create Canvas associated with your bitmap something like this

```
gCanvas = new Canvas();
gCanvas.setBitmap(yourBitmap);
```

and then use it as a canvas and draw what you want

EDIT: In case I wasn't clear, everything you draw on this canvas is like you draw on your bitmap. Then according to your X, Y get the color and compare

Hope this helps and enjoy your work

EDIT: Working example

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Bitmap image;
private int width;
private int height;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.clickete);

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();               

    width = display.getWidth();
    height = display.getHeight();

    createClickArea();

    findViewById(R.id.clickLayout).setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int result = whichCircle((int)event.getRawX(), (int)event.getRawY());
            Log.i("Color clicked: ", String.valueOf(result));
            return false;
        }
    });

    Drawable dr = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), image);        

    findViewById(R.id.clickLayout).setBackgroundDrawable(dr);
}

private void createClickArea(){
    Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; 

    image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, conf);

    Canvas gCanvas = new Canvas();
    gCanvas.setBitmap(image);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    gCanvas.drawRGB(0, 0, 0);       
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        switch(i){
        case 0: paint.setColor(Color.WHITE); break;
        case 1: paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW); break;
        case 2: paint.setColor(Color.BLUE); break;
        case 3: paint.setColor(Color.GREEN); break;
        }
        gCanvas.drawCircle((i + 1) * 80, (i + 1) * 80, 40, paint);
    }
}

private int whichCircle(int x, int y){
    int result = 0;
    int color = image.getPixel(x, y);
    switch(color){
    case Color.WHITE: result = 1; break;
    case Color.YELLOW: result = 2; break;
    case Color.BLUE: result = 3; break;
    case Color.GREEN: result = 4; break;
    }
    return result;
}

}
```

Just resolve deprecated methods and hide your bitmap, sorry but I don't have time to replace this now, my lunch is getting cold :)'. And remember work this in full screen or adjust your rawX, rawY according to your bitmap position.

Comment: I wanted to draw each circle a different color so as to recognize it, otherwise do not know what I clicked circle


for (...) {
int i = 0;
paint.setColor (i);
canvas.drawCircle (px, py, 70, paint);
}

Comment: Is this area visible at all? Why do you draw them just to see if someone clicked on it. How many of circles do you have? I would support your method if you have like 100's of them. But if you don't, just remember center points and radius and do some math through your array and first one that's in you go with it.
Or if you are sure you want this just tell what is a problem. You have your bitmap, and canvas to draw on, As I see you now how to draw it, and on click just ask bitmap of color

Comment: the bitmap is not visible at all, I just need to figure out the circle clicked and then figuring out its coordinates.
The goal is to connect 2 circles with a line and all made ​​by touch by the user.
Maybe you have some examples or tutorials that I can be of help?
Very nice thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one as to you can draw the bitmap as the background you want to draw first on the canvas in the ondraw function by implementing the surfaceholder.callback

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bgrReverse, fromRect2, toRect2, null);
```

then implement the onTouch() event in which you will get the pointer of the movement of the finger and getting those movement you can draw your circle to the received particular onTouch() and move of the finger.